# Parse dateTime string as UTC

Tags: javascript, luxon

Timezones is constant pain in every datetime library I tried. So here's the question, suppose you have a UTC datetime provided as string: `2019-06-25T05:00:00Z`. How do you create a UTC DateTime object out of it (I use luxon, but answer can be in terms of any library)?

```js
console.info(luxon.DateTime.fromISO('2019-06-25T05:00:00Z').toSQL());
```

```html
<script src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

When I run the snippet above I get:

```
2019-06-25 09:00:00.000 +04:00 // local timezone
```

While I need:

```
2019-06-25 05:00:00.000 -00:00 // UTC
```

Comment: Looks like you have to tell it to use UTC as the zone for the instance. It *parses* the string correctly, it's just using your local timezone when building a new string. I've updated my answer to show how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three options for you:

1) Luxon's documentation says you could use [`fromISO`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#static-method-fromISO) to get a `DateTime` from it. That *parses* the string correctly. Looks like to get it formatted the way you want, you have to tell it to use the zone UTC, but that's because it's formatting on *output*:

```js
const {DateTime} = luxon;
console.info(DateTime.fromISO('2019-06-25T05:00:00Z', { zone: "UTC"}).toSQL());
```

```html
<script src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

You could also use [`setZone("UTC")`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-setZone) on the result of `fromISO`.

2) JavaScript's built-in `Date` object will parse that as UTC (`new Date(yourString)`), since it's in the format [defined in the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format). You can then use the UTC methods on it to get the UTC information (`getUTCHours`, etc.), or you can use the local date/time methods on it to get the local information (`getHours`, etc.). You can also use `toISOString` to get a UTC string:

```js
console.info(new Date('2019-06-25T05:00:00Z').toISOString());
```

```html
<script src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

3) [Moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/) would also happily do so.

```js
console.info(moment.utc('2019-06-25T05:00:00Z').toISOString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you need `+00:00` instead of `Z`, you can throw a `replace` at it, or with Luxon or Moment they offer full formatting options.